# Get Title from ID

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, plugin

In a plugin I need to get the Title (from Article or Menu or Modules) from a given ID. I am using the following code and it's working but I would like to know if it is correct doing this way or is a better/more proper way of doing it.
Thank you.

```
$id      // ID from menu, article or module
$context // could be menu, content or module

$apk = JTable::getInstance($context);
$apk->load($id);
$title = $apk->get('title');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
public function onYOURFUNCTION($context, &$article, &$params)
{
    $id   = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getInt('id');
    $load = $article->load($id);

    echo $load->get('title');
}
```

or if you want to go down to JTable route:

```
public function onYOURFUNCTION($context, &$article, &$params)
{
    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getInt('id');
    $table = JTable::getInstance('content');
    $table->load($id);

    echo $table->get('title');
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! Is there any advantage from one method to another?

Comment: @n.h. - I believe in your case the first method would be best as the `&$article` object can be easily accessed as it already exists. `JTable` is an abstract class that allows selecting, updating and delete data from the database at ease, however you as mentioned above, you probably won't need it. I'm not a backend developer so I could be wrong about that. Perhaps someone else can elaborate.

Comment: @Lodder  JTable is more suitable if you need to access article params outside the article view. For example to get article image within template index.php and use it as a hero. In this case the first function would return null.